# Message: Undefined offset: 2

Tags: php, string, conversión-de-tipos

hola estoy tratando de convertir cada una, por separado, de las posiciones de un arreglo a un entero lo controlo con un for, yo busque informacion pero no pude encontrar como pasar cada una, solo salia pasar a entero todo el arreglo como una sola variable y no es lo que necesito.

codigo:

```
    for ($i=0; $i < $sizeArrAdv ; $i++) {


    $Yhire_date = $this->ol_model->getyearHire($arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"]);
    $Mhire_date = $this->ol_model->getmonthHire($arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"]);

        $Mhire_daten[$i] = (int)$Mhire_date[$i]["month"];
        $Yhire_daten[$i] = (int)$Yhire_date[$i]["year"];

            echo "".$yearCn;
            echo ",".$monthCn;
            print_r(",".$Yhire_daten[$i]);




            //print_r($arrayAdvocates[$i]);


            $u=($yearCn-$Yhire_daten[$i]["amo"])*12;
            $d=$u+($monthCn-1);
            $t=$d-$Mhire_daten[$i]["mes"];
            $monthworked [$i]=$t;

    if ($monthworked[$i] > 11){

    $mworked = array('advocate' => $arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"], 'Hire_Date' => $arrayhire_date[$i]["roster_hire_date"], 'Tenure' => $monthworked[$i], 'Type' => "T2", 'Bono' => "150.000");

     }

      array_push($arrayMtd, $mworked);
   }
```

me sale este error justo en estas dos lineas que es donde trato de hacer la conversion

```
    $Yhire_daten [$i]= (int)$Yhire_date[$i];
    $Mhire_daten[$i] = (int)$Mhire_date[$i];
```

codigo del error:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 2

Filename: controllers/Admin.php

Line Number: 716

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\olPrueba2\application\controllers\Admin.php
Line: 716
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\olPrueba2\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

pero cuando imprimo la variable si imprime el numero correctamente pero solo la primera vez que entra al for luego las imprime en 0 porque sale ese error y como lo corrijo,

esto es lo que imprimen los mensajes la primera vez del for como ves si imprime correctamente los datos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que imprime los siguientes casos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las líneas que dices es donde te arroja el error, no aparecen en tu primer código (al menos, no idénticas) ¿lo acortaste para acá no más?. ¿Podrías además señalarnos específicamente en qué parte le has dado a imprimir las variables dentro de este mismo código? Como dices que los valores aparecen correctos, tal vez viendo variable por variable, podamos encontrar a cuál offset se refiere como `undefined` (ya que recorres un ciclo, y usas el `$i` para moverte por él, tal vez el `array` no sea tan simétrico, etc.).

Comment: Gracias. Esas `$yearCn` y `$monthCn`, las traes de fuera del ciclo, cierto? Ahora, si dices que sólo te arroja valores correctos en la primera vuelta del ciclo, ahí está tu error de `undefined offset`: intentando acceder a un elemento que no existe. ¿Estás 100% seguro que todos los arrays que recorres dentro del ciclo tienen todos `$sizeArrAdv` elementos? Porque eso es lo que estás declarando en tu `for`.

Comment: si todos tienen el mismo numero de elementos, porque yo los estoy llenando en cada iteracion del for, cada que entra al for el guarda en la posicion de cada array segun sea $i,

Comment: Y ¿qué son `$Yhire_date` y `$Mhire_date`? Ya que los tratas como array. ¿Los has impreso para saber si contienen cada uno el índice al que accedes luego con `$i`? Te sugiero uses `print_r()` sobre cada uno.

Comment: imprimen bien, $Yhire_date= num del año, y $Mhire_date= num del mes, los traigo por medio de una consulta, y devuelve como un array por eso lo resibo como array y lo trato  como array, tuve que hacer un cambio para que imprimiera,el problema es cuando lo convierto a entero, ya que necesito operar con los datos de ese array, en esta linea le hago la conversion, $Mhire_daten[$i] = (int)$Mhire_date[$i]["month"];

Comment: $Yhire_date = $this->ol_model->getyearHire($arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"]);  LO CAMBIE POR ESTA , LE PUSE LA POSICION A ESE VECTOR AHORA CREO QUE DEBO ORGANIZAR CON ARRAY_PUSH   $Yhire_date[$i] = $this->ol_model->getyearHire($arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"]);el error sigue en las lineas donde hago la conversion osea en $Yhire_daten es distinta a $Yhire_date, la primera guarda el string e imprime bien y la segunda guarda un entero pero imprime un (1 ) y el año es (2017)

Comment: Y en cuanto a la conversión, ¿no has usado la funcionalidad base de PHP, de simplemente asignar el valor "entero" a las variables? Me refiero a un sencillo: `$Mhire_daten[$i] = $Mhire_date[$i]["month"] + 0;`... O incluso, puedes averiguar antes el tipo de variable usando `is_int()` o similares ([documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.var.php)).